Advice about image ratio in CSS or Tailwind
My screen shot
Hey I have a problem (potentially with tailwind) with my images ratio.
All is working well on mobile and on desktop/laptop unless the window starts to be near full screen.
                     <div class="relative w-full lg:h-74 h-full sm:px-4">
                            <a href="<?= htmlspecialchars($post['imagepath']) ?>"  data-caption="Caption">
                            <img src="<?= htmlspecialchars($post['imagepath']) ?>" alt="" class="sm:rounded-lg w-full h-full object-cover">
                            </a>
                     </div>

I tried changing the values but it didn't help...
Is there a chance someone can help with this?

Why dont you use aspect-video in the img ? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/aspect-ratio

It didn't work... What is weird is everything is perfect until the window is 80% of the screen

I cant replicate the problem with default tailwind settings . I'm going to put an answer with an example of code, so you can compare if you get the same. Also, if you want to try to set an aspect ratio with css is just an aspect-ratio: 16/9

The first 4 items are the ones i made that set an aspect ratio with tailwind classes, then the other 4 are the html you set in the question with default tailwind settings. I can't get them in 16:9 with your code, you must have other styles affecting the ratio.


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="container mx-auto py-16">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-4 gap-4">
            <div class="p-4 border rounded-xl">
                <a href="#"  data-caption="Caption">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" class="rounded-lg w-full object-cover aspect-video">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="p-4 border rounded-xl">
                <a href="#"  data-caption="Caption">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" class="rounded-lg w-full object-cover aspect-video">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="p-4 border rounded-xl">
                <a href="#"  data-caption="Caption">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" class="rounded-lg w-full object-cover aspect-video">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="p-4 border rounded-xl">
                <a href="#"  data-caption="Caption">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" class="rounded-lg w-full object-cover aspect-video">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container mx-auto py-16">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-4 gap-4">
            <div class="relative w-full lg:h-74 h-full sm:px-4">
                <a href="#"  data-caption="Caption">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="" class="sm:rounded-lg w-full h-full object-cover">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="relative w-full lg:h-74 h-full sm:px-4">
                <a href="#"  data-caption="Caption">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" class="sm:rounded-lg w-full h-full object-cover">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="relative w-full lg:h-74 h-full sm:px-4">
                <a href="#"  data-caption="Caption">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" class="sm:rounded-lg w-full h-full object-cover">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="relative w-full lg:h-74 h-full sm:px-4">
                <a href="#"  data-caption="Caption">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" class="sm:rounded-lg w-full h-full object-cover">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



